# Android alert disappear

Tags: android, browser, bitmap, alert

I made an alert in my app
and it's perfect in my main activity where I want it
but I want it to disappears after three times of warning the person .. not every time I get back to the main Activity it appears

this is my alert code

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder( this )
    .setTitle( "Browser feature" )
    .setMessage( "The browser feature is currently beta, so it won't work perfectly. To get an image from the internet, click on the browser then google your image, and save it then import it using the gallery option." )
    .setPositiveButton( "Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d( "AlertDialog", "Positive" );
        }
    })
    .show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the number of times the person has been warned as a SharedPreference.  Update each time the counter and then only issue if they count < 3.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Shared preferences is the best place to keep this type of global information.